# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway - Django - Gunicorn - When running MySQL reports (Stored Procedures) that take longer than 30 seconds

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django, Nginx, Gunicorn, and MySQL on AWS.

Running a postback from django which calls a stored procedure that takes longer than 30 seconds to complete causes a return of "502 Bad Gateway" nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).

It sure looks like a timeout issue and that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816215/gunicorn-nginx-timeout-problem) should resolve it.

But alas, it doesn't seem to be working.

---

Here is my gunicorn.conf file:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling formManagement django app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/AARC-ServiceManager/ServerSide/formManagement

exec ve/bin/gunicorn --timeout 300 --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/AARC-ServiceManager/ServerSide/formManagement/formManagement.sock formManagement.wsgi:application
```

And my Nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
                worker_connections 768;
                # multi_accept on;
}

http {

                ##
                # Basic Settings
                ##

                # set client body size (max http request size) #
                client_max_body_size 50M;

                #upping the timeouts to allow time for the DB to return from a long running sproc
                proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;

                sendfile on;
                tcp_nopush on;
                tcp_nodelay on;
                keepalive_timeout 65;
                types_hash_max_size 2048;
                # server_tokens off;

                # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
                # server_name_in_redirect off;

                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;

                ##
                # Logging Settings
                ##

                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                ##
                # Gzip Settings
                ##

                gzip on;
                gzip_disable "msie6";


                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
                include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

---

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
This is the error in the nginx error log:
[error] 14316#0: *13 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream ...

Comment: Do you have an idea of how long the transaction is actually taking?

Comment: @Dashdrum Hey Dashdrum. Yes, I created a stored proc to reproduce the error. When I "sleep" the proc for 35 seconds, the error occurs.

Comment: Is the request originated from ajax?

Comment: @serg Thanks for your comment serg. The request is originating from a postback. I also just discovered what was wrong - I'm posting the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the resolution!

I was updating the wrong gunicorn.conf file.

I saved to config file to my source control and when I was in the server, was updating that file.

However, I needed to be changing the file at location:

```
/etc/init/gunicorn.conf
```

... and I learned a lesson about having more than one config file on the server.

Thanks all who were offering help.